# Pure CSS Animation refuses to...animate

Tags: html, css

I have a pure CSS animation that I am working on (first time doing one) and I can't seem to get the drawing to move.  http://jsfiddle.net/c6kBj/30/

I am not really sure what the problem is, but it's pretty frustrating.

Here is the code in case you don't feel like going to the jsfiddle:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="beeBody">
        <div id="rear" class="beePart beeStripe"></div>
        <div id="front" class="beePart beeStripe"></div>
        <div class="beePart beeStinger"></div>
        <div class="beePart beeHead"></div>
        <div class="beePart beeEye"></div>
        <div class="beePart beePupil"></div>
        <div class="beePart beeSmile"></div>
        <div class="beePart beeAntenna"></div>
        <div class="beePart beeWing" id="front-right"></div>
        <div class="beePart beeWing" id="front-left"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.bg{
    height: 500px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: green;
}

.beeBody {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    background-color: black;
    border-left: 5px solid yellow;
    border-right: 5px solid yellow;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-animation: buzz 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: buzz 3s infinite;
    animation: buzz 3s infinite;
}

.beePart {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.beeStripe {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-top: 9px;
    border-top: solid yellow 1px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    border-bottom: solid yellow 1px;
    border-left: solid yellow 3px;
    border-right: solid yellow 3px;
}

    .beeStripe#rear {
        left: 5px;
        top: -10px;
    }

    .beeStripe#front {
        left: -10px;
        top: -30px;
    }

.beeStinger {
    border-top: solid transparent 2px;
    border-bottom: solid transparent 2px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: solid black 12.5px;
    left: -37px;
    top: -42px;
}

.beeHead {
    border: 12px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    top: -57px;
    left: 20px;
}

.beeEye {
    border-top: solid white 6px;
    border-bottom: solid white 6px;
    border-left: solid white 3px;
    border-right: solid white 3px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    top: -81px;
    left: 36px;
}

.beePupil {
    z-index: 20;
    border-top: solid black 3px;
    border-bottom: solid black 3px;
    border-left: solid black 1.5px;
    border-right: solid black 1.5px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    top: -90px;
    left: 39px;
}

.beeSmile {
    border-bottom: solid yellow 1px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    top: -85px;
    left: 31.5px;
}

.beeAntenna {
    border-left: solid black 1.5px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 16px;
    top: -114px;
    left: 35px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.beeWing {
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px / 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px / 40px;
    border-radius: 20px / 40px;
    top: -140px;
    left: -5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    opacity: .8;
}

    .beeWing#front-left {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
        transform: rotate(-50deg);
        top: -175px;
        left: -10px;
    }

@keyframes buzz {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-5px) translateX(0) rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-5px) translateX(0) rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px) translateX(0) rotate(30deg);
        transform: translateY(-5px) translateX(0) rotate(30deg);
    }

    25% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(5px) translateX(25%) rotate(20deg);
        -ms-transform: translateY(5px) translateX(25%) rotate(20deg);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(5px) translateX(25%) rotate(20deg);
        transform: translateY(5px) translateX(25%) rotate(20deg);
    }

    50% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(10px) translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(10px) translateX(50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) translateX(50%);
        transform: translateY(10px) translateX(50%);
    }

    75% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(5px) translateX(75%) rotate(-20deg);
        -ms-transform: translateY(5px) translateX(75%) rotate(-20deg);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(5px) translateX(75%) rotate(-20deg);
        transform: translateY(5px) translateX(75%) rotate(-20deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-17px) translateX(100%) rotate(-40deg);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-17px) translateX(100%) rotate(-40deg);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-17px) translateX(100%) rotate(-40deg);
        transform: translateY(-17px) translateX(100%) rotate(-40deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works on Firefox 27.0...

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome it gives some kind of error but it's not on your end...
GET http://jobs.jsfiddle.net/random.js?callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This doesn't work in latest versions of Chrome v25, Opera, IE9, or Safari.

Comment: You might have to prefix the `translate` property too. EG (`-webkit-transform: -webkit-translateY(10px) -webkit-translateX(50%);`

Comment: +1 on the bee as div objects. nice work!

Comment: I am using Chrome.  See the answer below by Jonathon Dumaine.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/24ZGT/1/

You were missing @-webkit-keyframe & @-moz-keyframe in addition to your @keyframe. It kind of sucks right now writing all of that, so I would suggest using some sort of CSS preprocessor that handles that for you to save yourself typing time and debugging time sorting through verbose CSS.

For example, with Stylus & Nib you could write your keyframe just like this:

```
@keyframes buzz
    0%
        transform translateY(-5px) translateX(0) rotate(30deg)

    25%
        transform translateY(5px) translateX(25%) rotate(20deg)

    50%
        transform translateY(10px) translateX(50%)

    75%
        transform translateY(5px) translateX(75%) rotate(-20deg)

   100%
        transform translateY(-17px)
```

And Stylus would output all the prefixed versions for you!

Comment: This fixed the problem.  Thanks!  Darn those vendor specific tags!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c6kBj/36/

You need to prefix the animation as well:

```
...
@keyframes buzz {...}
@-ms-keyframes buzz {...}
@-webkit-keyframes buzz {...}
...
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/